# Are both sentences correct? "He is sleeping now." and "He sleeps now."

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

If so, is there any difference in meaning and the field of use?
Can "He sleeps now." be considered grammatically wrong?

Comment: This brings to mind the supposed Sicilian expression as quoted in _The Godfather_ ..."he sleeps with the fishes."

Comment: 'He sleeps now' for 'He's asleep at the moment' is antiquated / literary. 'He is sleeping now' is a lot better in everyday use, but on the formal side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are technically correct, though the former is a lot better. The latter is a bit awkward to say, due to the irregular way of using the simple present tense.

The simple present tense is used for habitual or factual actions, as in; *he works on Fridays*. It is something he does, though he is not doing it right now.

That is what we use present participle for, things that are happening right now. If set person is sleeping right now, as we are speaking, then I would use the first option; "He is sleeping now". Though, the other option is correct, and could be used to one's advantage, as to perhaps highlight a trait with the person saying it, i.e. that they're a bit socially awkward, or that English is there second language. Also, the latter option could even sound poetic, as said by someone siting a legend.

> He sleeps now... but one day he shall awaken.

So, there are places one can use the simple present in situations like this. Here's a link if you want further explaining, or if you found my explanation worded badly. http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/simple_present.htm

Comment: @AKvåle  'He _shall_ awaken". _Shalt_ belongs only with _thou_.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I'm currently trying to learn Shakespearean, so you're comment is highly appreciated. @KateBunting

Comment: Both sentences are *grammatical*, if that's what you mean by *technically correct.*

Comment: @PeterShor Yeah, that's what I meant.